# How can I change this loop in Vue so that I can have a <tr> the full length below each row?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm looking to achieve something like this - https://codepen.io/jopico/pen/kyRprJ

But with Vue.

```html
<tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <tr v-for="row in paginatedReleases" :key="row.id">
        <td v-for="column in columnsReleases" 
            :key="column.accessorKey"
            class="whitespace-nowrap py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 px-4">
            <span v-if="typeof column.cell === 'function'">{{ column.cell({ getValue: () => row[column.accessorKey] }) }}</span>
            <span v-else>{{ row[column.accessorKey] }}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
        <div class="fold-content">
            <h3>Fold Example Text</h3>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>         
        </div>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There is a td missing in your example - are you asking how to set the correct colspan on it, i.e. `<td :colspan=""columnsReleases.length>`?